# Dynamically intercept all sub domains in plain HTML/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, routes, web-frontend

Im working on an old web page which has a monolithic structure. I have a switch statement which checks for the pathname of the URL and then runs few functions which hide or show elements on the page.

```
switch(window.location.pathname){
   case '/admin/myapp/myappcategory/add/':
       $('#change_id_primary_category').hide();
       $('#add_id_primary_category').hide();
       break;
```

Now I have to ensure that urls which are nested under the add category also can be intercepted. Example:

```
    /admin/myapp/mayappcategory/add/3,
    /admin/myapp/mayappcategory/add/5
```

While Im familiar with routing using React router, Im unsure of how to dynamically intercept all the urls after add in the above switch statement.
I tried adding wildcards, but I couldnt make it work. Any suggestions to handle the same would be greatly appreciated. The current project uses jQuery and vanilla JS/HTMl for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex instead:

```
if(window.location.pathname.match(/\/admin\/myapp\/mayappcategory\/add\/(\d)+/)){
    // do your thing here..
}
```

I'm not sure if you have to use the switch case. Also I assume your dynamic parameter is an int, but if that's not the case you can always tweak the regex